# Add stored proc and call it from a service

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql

1. I create a simple stored procedure with some joins with the customer table and other related tables, which takes in two parameters. I can execute this SP in SQL and works.
2. I drag and drop this SP to my DBML file and recompile.
3. I add the below code in order to call the SP and return it in a List

   ```
   public IQueryable<Entities.Customer> AllCustomerRanges(int CId, int ItemID)
   {
       List<Entities.Customer> c = myDataContext.spCustomerRanges(CId, ItemID).ToList();

   }
   ```

This gives me the error:

*Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List< spCustomerRangesResult>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List< Entities.Customer>'*

Now i dont have a class spCustomerRangesResult but after some research I'm puzzled if i have done something wrong or if i need to implement a class with all the properties that the Customer class has (which sounds a little long winded) or if i've just made an error.

Any idea of how i can call a SP which shows the data in a List?

Comment: I did have a look at that but im not using EF6

Comment: Sorry I mixed up EDMX and DMBL (which I don't even know what that is)

Comment: Try using "var c = ..." and see what properties that gives you. It is possible that spCustomerRangesResult has a results property or value property which will return you an entities.customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new class spCustomerRangesResult automatically generated based on sp result, you should convert it to Entities.Customer like this:

```
      public IQueryable<Entities.Customer> AllCustomerRanges(int CId, int ItemID)
        {
            var c = myDataContext.spCustomerRanges(CId, ItemID).ToList();

            if (c == null)
                return null;

            var customers = c.Select(a => new Entities.Customer
            {
                FirstName=a.spResultFirstName,
                LastName = a.spResultLastName
                //this just example conversion, change it as needed. 
            });


            return customers;

        }
```

please note, that I return IQueryable even though the approach that you take when using ToList() but yet returning IQuerybale may not be needed. I dont know all details so this only to show how to convert but the whole method may need re-factoring.